# Bootstrap div columns not aligning vertically in row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my first post, because I'm stuck on the first part of making my first website.

I'm trying to make a navigation bar with five parts:

**(Vertical list of 3 items) (Label) (Logo) (Label) (Vertical list of 3 items)**

For example, 
**(Apples, Oranges, Pears) (Fruits) (Logo) (Vegetables) (Broccoli, Celery, Lettuce)**

With my code, the two vertical lists aren't aligned with each other, and I can't get any of them to center vertically in the bar.

This is my code:

HTML

```
<body>
<div class='nav'>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-3'>
                <ul class='port-list' class='navbar-left'>
                    <li>Art</li>
                    <li>Design</li>
                    <li>Writing</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class='col-md-3'>
                <p class='port'>Portfolio</p>
            </div>

            <img>

            <div class='col-md-3'>
                <p class='about'>About</p>
            </div>

            <div class='col-md-3'>
                <ul class='about-list' class='navbar-right'>
                    <li>Biography</li>
                    <li>R&eacute;sum&eacute;</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}

body {
    height: 100%; /* Prevents rubber-band scrolling */
    overflow: hidden; /* Prevents rubber-band scrolling */
}

.nav {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Donegal One', serif;
    background-color: #004d40;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    display: block;
}

.port-list {
    text-align: right;
}

.port {
    text-align: left;
}

.about {
    text-align: right;
}

.about-list {
    text-align: left;
}
```

This here newbie would appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nafHt)?

Comment: @Tushar, that's exactly it.  Thank you!

Comment: I have added answer, how you can do it. You may accept it if it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nafHt) is the updated code

HTML

```
<div class='row newRow'>
```

Added `newRow` to `row`
CSS

```
.newRow {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.newRow .col-md-3 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: none
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Tushar!  I'd upvote you, but it won't let me because my reputation isn't at least 15.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `line-height` for both div as follow:

```
<div class='col-md-3' style="line-height:58px;">
      <p class='port'>Portfolio</p>
</div>
....
<div class='col-md-3' style="line-height:58px;">
     <p class='about'>About</p>
</div>
```